# How to grab text with newlines in a text file?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I have a text file with the below content:

> .....
>
> Phone:     123-456-7899, 555-555-5555, 999-333-7890
>
> Names:     Bob Jones, Mary Smith, Bob McAlly,
>
> Sally Fields, Tom Hanks, Jeffery Cook,
>
> Betty White, Tom McDonald, Bruce Harris
>
> Address:  1234 Main, 445 Westlake, 3332 Front Street
>    .....

I am looking to grab all of the names starting from Bob Jones and ending with Bruce Harris from the file.  I have this Scala code, but it only gets the first line:

> Bob Jones, Mary Smith, Bob McAlly,

Here is the code:

```
val addressBookRDD = sc.textFile(file);
val myRDD = addressBookRDD.filter(line => line.contains("Names: ")
```

I don’t know how to deal with the returns or newlines in the text file, so the code only grabs the first line of the names, but not the rest of the names which are separate lines. I am looking for this type of result:

> Bob Jones, Mary Smith, Bob McAlley, Sally Fields, Tom Hanks, Jeffery
>   Cook, Betty White, Tom McDonald, Bruce Harris

Comment: I would recommend to not use Spark to read this file (due to it's structure), it will only create trouble for you. Use pure Scala code instead.

Comment: So, is there any way to grab all of the names from the text file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I pointed out in a comment, to read a file structured this way is not really something Spark is very suitable for. If the file is not very large, using only Scala would probably be a better way to do it. Here is a Scala implementation:

```
val lines = scala.io.Source.fromFile(file).getLines
val nameLines = lines
  .dropWhile(line => !line.startsWith("Names: "))
  .takeWhile(line  => !line.startsWith("Address: "))
  .toSeq
val names = (nameLines.head.drop(7) +: nameLines.tail)
  .mkString(",")
  .split(",")
  .map(_.trim)
  .filter(_.nonEmpty)
```

Printing names using `names foreach println` will give you:

```
Bob Jones
Mary Smith
Bob McAlly
Sally Fields
Tom Hanks
Jeffery Cook
Betty White
Tom McDonald
Bruce Harris
```